# Why does not date input does not return None if nothing is passed?

Tags: django

Here is my html code

```
<form method="GET" class="container mb-5">
    <label for="inputDate">Enter the date:</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1 mr-2">С:</div>
                <input class="col-10" type="date" class="form-control" name="searchdate" value="{{ value1 }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 ml-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-1 mr-3">До:</div>
                <input class="col-10" type="date" class="form-control" name="searchto" value="{{ value_3 }}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary px-5" >Search</button>
</form>


    {{ value1 }} {{ value_3 }}
```

and here is my views:

```
def profile(request):
    value_one = request.GET.get("searchdate", None)
    value_three = request.GET.get("searchto", None)
    return render(request,'personal.html',{'value1':value_one,'value3':value_three})
```

The date appears in html only if I input something, but when I don't set any date it is just blank page, however on the website should be displyed 'None None', shouldn't it?

Comment: The key _is present_ in the GET parameters, only the values are empty strings for them, which is why instead of `None` you get a blank page.

Comment: If you used a Django form it would clean the incoming data and return None when no value was supplied

Comment: you've also got a typo: value_3 in template, context is 'value3'